# properties attributeName in SVF2 changed

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

when comparing SVF <> SVF2 I noticed that the attributenames in the properties are changed in SVF2.
This would mean a lot of rework in my code. Because I use them in filtering the "GetBulkProperties" result

Also the attributeNames are no longer unique, for instance "Category" or "Type" give multiple results.
Any reason why they are changed?
is there another way of filtering the properties result?[image attributeName SVF - SVF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDgaB.png)

Comment: This is a bit offtopic but I recommend using CategoryId for category related code. This will help a lot for internationalization, the categoryId does not change when using models in other language.

Comment: On your topic, why are you not using the displayName value?

Comment: in SFV attributeName is unique, displayName is not. In SVF2 attributeName and DisplayName are the same

Comment: Can you confirm that this is the *same* file that's being converted into SVF(1) and SVF2? The reason I'm asking is - I believe that the `LcRevitData_Element...` is a new way if ID'ing properties that was actually introduced in the latest version of Revit.

Comment: And if it *is* the same file, could you please share it with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` (confidentially, only within Autodesk) so that we can debug it on our end?

Comment: @petr-broz We connect to BIM360 Docs with forge viewer. So yes it is the same file.
In my experience a Revit property attributeName was allways "LcRevitData..." for most properties . Should I send you a file or give you access to a test project on our BIM360 DOcs env.?

Comment: Ah I see. Sharing the file with us would be easier (in case one of my colleagues or one of our developers needs to access it as well).